# Creating GIF thumbnail using node-quickthumb

Tags: node.js, gif

I am trying to create a thumbnail of GIF image.

I searched in all possible Stack Overflow links, But, I am not getting exact reason for my error.

I have also added a screenshot of the error.
[image]

Also if anyone could provide library to create thumbnail of GIF file.

Any help would be appreciated.